# Is it possible or how to compute additional iterations in C# Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, pbkdf2

I'd like to increase iteration count for existing passwords. Is it possible with Rfc2898DeriveBytes? My weak attempt obviously doesn't work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        using (var c = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            c.GetBytes(salt);
        }
        
        byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password");

        const int currentIterationCount = 100;
        const int newIterationCount = 1000;

        byte[] partialHash = Compute(password, salt, currentIterationCount, 32);
        byte[] finalHash = Compute(partialHash, salt, newIterationCount - currentIterationCount, 32);

        byte[] onetimeHash = Compute(password, salt, newIterationCount, 32);
        
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(finalHash));   // N2HOBoubZfcOV9my3SIH8+KH9khvtCUSoRDDWkJJpMg=
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(onetimeHash)); // EnBixdGRX+Y6P1qNcKGYrbzxusn3b4Yvo3Shw7/8L7Y=
        Console.WriteLine(finalHash == onetimeHash);            // False

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static byte[] Compute(byte[] valueToHash, byte[] salt, int iterations, int hashSize)
    {
        using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(valueToHash, salt, iterations))
        {
            return pbkdf2.GetBytes(hashSize);
        }
    }
}
```

I am also currently limited to .net standard 2.0/.net framework 4.7.2

Comment: You'd have to wait until the user logged in again, so that you have the password, then you can create the hash with more iterations and store that. You'd have to record in the database how many iterations were used for the hash, and check that to see if it was the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the number of rounds without knowing the password as in every round PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 computes HMAC-SHA1(password, H) where H is the output of HMAC-SHA1 from the previous round.

Hence, a common solution is to remove all the old passwords from your database and require users to create new ones.

Also, as Andrew Morton has suggested, new hashes could be created on the fly for a short period of time when users log in.

In any case, an iteration count of 1000 is not much nowadays. You should use a higher value if you can afford it. You should also consider moving to a better password-hashing functions such as Argon2id.